# GoDaddy running wrong javaScript file

Tags: jquery, cpanel

On my domain I have linked a javaScript file to my html and uploaded it. There was an old version of this file on my server but now I have updated it. When I open it in Cpanel's editor the file is the new script however when I run the html file and look in the Sources tab on chrome it shows the old jQuery code. I searched my domain and there is only 1 file with that name.

Comment: I did try and look and obviously didn't find a solution and that's why I asked here,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is probably being served with caching headers that prevent the browser from reloading the file immediately.

You can empty your browser's cache and do a hard reload - that should give you the right version.

If this is a live site, however, any visitors that have already been to your site will continue getting the old script.

You don't necessarily want to turn off those caching headers, though: the browser not reloading the JS file every time you hit one of your pages is a *good* thing.

One way to make sure the browser reloads the file when changes occur is to add something to the URL that makes the file look new and different. Many people do this in an ordered fashion, e.g. like so:

```
<script src="myscript.js?version=1">
```

Now whenever something changes in `myscript.js`, they increment `version` in the HTML and make sure every visitor's browser loads the new file. Any subsequent visits get the cached file; next time, something changes, change `version` to 3, and so on and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps reset your cache?

(assuming google chrome)

Right click and inspect element anywhere on the page, and then right click the browser refresh button and click 'empty cache and hard reload'